# Fill the missing Data in table based on other table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, metadata

I have a data set which looks like this: Table1

```
Date       A           B          C           D .......
1-Oct      0.3         0.1                    1
2-3ct      0.5         0.9        0.6         
3-Oct                             0.8         0.4
```

And another set which looks like this: Table2

```
Date       A           B          C           D .......
1-Oct      0.5         0.4        0.3          1
2-Oct      0.7         0.6        0.7         0.6 
3-Oct      1           0.9        0.8         0.4
```

I want my output in a way wherever table 1 data is present it should reflect in the output data, if in any of the column if table 1 data is missing it should get fill by table 2 Data. so my output will look like:

```
Date       A           B          C           D .......
1-Oct      0.3         0.1        0.3          1        ---0.3 filled in since it was not present in Table1
2-3ct      0.5         0.9        0.6         0.6       
3-Oct      1           0.9        0.8         0.4
```

can anyone help me how to get the output data in this form....Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df = df1.combine_first(df2)
```